# what is scrollY?

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

when I use setScrollY for TextView , it's userfull. but when I use setScrollY for RecyclerView , it's seem has some wrong.

---

Code is:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "mContactTextView.getScrollY():" + mContactTextView.getScrollY());
mContactTextView.setScrollY(800);
Log.d("MainActivity", "mContactTextView.getScrollY():" + mContactTextView.getScrollY());

Log.d("MainActivity", "mRecyclerView.getScrollY():" + mRecyclerView.getScrollY());
mRecyclerView.setScrollY(200);
Log.d("MainActivity", "mRecyclerView.getScrollY():" + mRecyclerView.getScrollY());
```

---

LogCat is:

```
01-19 10:54:44.496 29448-29448/com.example.ice.test D/MainActivity: mContactTextView.getScrollY():0
01-19 10:54:44.496 29448-29448/com.example.ice.test D/MainActivity: mContactTextView.getScrollY():800
01-19 10:54:44.496 29448-29448/com.example.ice.test D/MainActivity: mRecyclerView.getScrollY():0
01-19 10:54:44.496 29448-29448/com.example.ice.test D/MainActivity: mRecyclerView.getScrollY():0
```

---

although is has output 800 for TextView , in fact , it has't move down for 800 px.

I don't know why,Can someone would like share knowledge?

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: @Mr.Robot java8